# How to get past a forgotten iPhone passcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, password, ipados

I forgot my iPhone 5 passcode when I was changing the code. A window appeared on the device screen saying that iPhone is disabled.

I have Apple ID and password for it. After signing in to iCloud I have erased the device in order to remove the passcode from my iPhone but it still says that device will be erased when device will connect to internet. What would i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Connect the device to a Mac over USB and restore it using Finder. Since you have control of the AppleID that locks that device, you only need to get it connected to a network again. You can also see the last backup date online and know how much data might be lost in a restore.

Once the restore process is complete, you can restore the backup or just set up the phone as new. The apps, data, passcode will all be erased.

Comment: I think you mean treat as a new device rather than restore for the first step?

Comment: @WGroleau No, I’m presuming they have a backup and therefore you’d almost certainly want to use it over starting from scratch.

Comment: If they don’t know the passcode, restoring a backup will restore the same conditions.  Treating it as new will clear that—but now that I think of it, restoring the previous backup after will put it back.

Comment: I edited this to be clear - wipe is the simplest answer - some people might want a more nuanced solution of course, but the way past a passcode is to wipe.

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone has ever been connected to internet on WiFi, go to the same place.  It will connect again and erase.

If it has a SIM card and a valid cell contract with data, and you had not turned off cell data, it will connect and erase as soon as it gets a reasonable cell signal.

If none of those, connecting to a MacOS device and setting it up as new will erase non-default  apps and data.  You can then login with your Apple ID and download any apps you’ve added from the App Store and any data that had been in iCloud.  Data that was only local will be gone.